# Javascript : What is the best way to detect combination of two keys in array of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Lets say:

```
var person = [
    {"classKey": 1, "teacherKey": 1},
    {"classKey": 2, "teacherKey": 1},
    {"classKey": 2, "teacherKey": 1}
]
```

How do i prevent the duplicated record to be added, or even how to remove the duplicated combinated pairs?

Thank you

Comment: so you would need to loop over each index and see if there is a match

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)

Comment: yes, but using two different keys @epascarello

Comment: So you check both... if (person[i].classKey==X && person[i].teacherKey==Y) { console.log(`we have a match`) }

Comment: @sectus OP would need to use a hash / checksum of some sort to uniquely identify each entry so I don't think it's quite the same thing

Comment: @Phil, you are write. OP would need compare function for his objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thing you want to do is uniquely identify each entry.

A very quick way would be to concatenate the values into a delimited string, eg

```
let key = [entry.classKey, entry.teacherKey].join(':')
```

You could then use this to keep track of existing entries and [filter the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). For example, using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)...

```js
const person = [
    {"classKey": 1, "teacherKey": 1},
    {"classKey": 2, "teacherKey": 1},
    {"classKey": 2, "teacherKey": 1}
]

const filtered = person.filter(function(entry) {
  let key = [entry.classKey, entry.teacherKey].join(':')
  return !this.has(key) && !!this.add(key)
}, new Set())

console.info(filtered)
```

I'm using a some boolean short-circuiting to keep it brief but if it helps explain what's going on, it works like this

```
if (set.has(key)) {
  return false // filter out the duplicate value
} else {
  set.add(key) // record the key
  return true // keep this value
}
```

---

If you're not keen on using a `Set` (possibly due to browser compatibility) you could instead keep track using a plain object

```
const filtered = person.filter(function(entry) {
  let key = [entry.classKey, entry.teacherKey].join(':')
  return !this[key] && (this[key] = true)
}, Object.create(null))
```

Comment: I havent used this code before..
Hm..
Interesting..
What does the if do?

if(this[key]) return false?

Means it exists?

Comment: @BrianRuchiadi I've change it to use a `Set` to keep track of existing entries. I hope that makes more sense